# Opening an URL in external browser when newViewRequested signal emited

Tags: qt, browser, qml, qt5, qtwebengine

I Use WebEngineView QML Type to show a web page that have some link that need to open in a new tab. Links are somethings like

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Go to google in new tab</a>
```

I want to open the URL of [newViewRequested signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#newViewRequested-signal) in an external browser but the [WebEngineNewViewRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webenginenewviewrequest.html) has no 'url' property that I can use with `Qt.openUrlExternally(request.url)`.

`WebEngineNewViewRequest`  has a private member [QUrl m_requestedUrl](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/src/webengine/api/qquickwebenginenewviewrequest_p.h) that not accesible as property in qml.
How can I handle the issue,get the URL and open it in an external browser.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt5, you can use [navigationRequested](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#navigationRequested-signal) signal to achieve this:

```
onNavigationRequested: function(request) {
    if (request.navigationType === WebEngineNavigationRequest.LinkClickedNavigation) {
        Qt.openUrlExternally(request.url)
    }
    request.action = WebEngineNavigationRequest.IgnoreRequest
}
```

The line of assigning `IgnoreRequest` to the `action` property is to make sure the URL is not opened in the WebEngineView.